# Need help with using Bessel functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm new to Bessel functions, especially those of the first kind. I'm working with a problem that goes as such:

[image]
[image]

With that said, is my code for said problem correct?

```
α = 0.5; β = 0.3; M = 12;
m = Range[M];
γ = N[BesselJZero[m, M]];
g = (BesselJ[1, m]/(γ^2 (BesselJ[1, m])^2)) BesselJ[
    1, γ]*Tanh[β*γ];
Total[g]
```

Comment: What do you mean by $\gamma_m$, `BesselJZero[1,m]`?  There is  `Bessel[1`, $\gamma_m$`]`   both in numerator and denominator in the definition of `g`, so it seems that your definitione isn`t optimal, is it?.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I don't know what is considered the "inverse" of the Bessel function to solve for γm

Comment: Your comment isn't clear, there is no inverse function in your definition of `g`.

Comment: That's what I mean. If no inverse exists, I can't use that for γm.

Comment: You have coded `BesselJ[ 1, m ]`, where $m$ is a range of integers.  The formula contains a different expression.  You have also coded `BesselJZero[ m, M ]`, which will give the 12th zero of each function $J_1, J_2, J_3, ... J_{12}$ .

Comment: Ooooooooh now I get it. The `BesselJZero[]` was the "inverse" I was looking for! Now that I know that the function is Listable and what I was missing, I can solve proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you code is correct.

1. You have left `α` out your term definition.
2. `m` shouldn't be defined as a range, but kept as an unevaluated indexing variable.
3. `γ` needs to be a function of the index `m` defined as:

   `γ[m_] := N[BesselJZero[0, m]]`
4. You should use `Sum` in place of `Total`.

With these changes a term of `g` becomes

```
term[m_] := BesselJ[1, α γ[m]] Tanh[β γ[m]] / BesselJ[1, γ[m]] / γ[m]^2
```

and `g`, itself, is evaluated by

```
α = 0.5; β = 0.3; mMax = 12;
g = Sum[term[m], {m, mMax}]
```

> `0.064631`

#### Update

The following is added to address concerns raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

The value of `γ[m]` for a positive integer `m` is the value at which the *m*-th zero occurs in `BesselJ[0, z]`.  That this is indeed so can seen by

```
BesselJ[0, #] & /@ γ /@ Range[mMax] // Chop
>`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`
```

These values, `γ /@ Range[mMax]`, do not necessarily correspond to zeros of `BesselJ[1, z]`.

Comment: Oh darn, I am missing a variable. But I'm confused tho, how it that you interpret the Bessel Zero function to make the gamma variables when the gamma variables are suppose to make zeros when given gamma terms?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to m_goldberg for the help! But given that the book didn't specify the `Sum[]` function, here's a version with `Total[]` instead, which yields the same answer regardless:

```
α = 0.5; β = 0.3; M = 12;
m = Range[M];
γ = N[BesselJZero[0, m]];
g = (BesselJ[1, α γ]/(γ^2 (BesselJ[1, γ])^2)) BesselJ[1, γ]*Tanh[β*γ];
Total[g]
```

Comment: This is good, It makes use of `Listable` attribute of numeric functions such as `BesselJZero` and `BesselJ`.